# Unable to setitems in tableview

Tags: javafx-8

What does this error mean?

```
setItems (javafx.collections.Observablelist<java.lang.String> in TableView cannot be applied to (javafx.collections.ObservableList<sample.Menu>)
```

I have a class called `Menu` and a package called sample.

Comment: It means the type parameter of your `TableView` does not match the type parameter of the `ObservableList` you pass to the `setItem` method. Just take a look at the method signature: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setItems(javafx.collections.ObservableList)

Comment: Oh I see yup I fixed it thanks!